# Jquery AJAX save image of textarea

Tags: jquery

I am trying to save an image of my textarea, 'dynamically',  with the html content in this area, for example an editied html email template. Is there anyway to do this via Jquery, Ajax?.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you have an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: What have you already tried? You might try experimenting with Canvas, but I don't think you're going to have much luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

You should send the element information, content and position to the server and create a picture there using that information.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Vtortola, figured it would be along these lines-Do you have an example of how this might be done? using, Ajax? Thanks

Comment: take a look on this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/d9b69701-85ba-439c-9737-e36f78f65acf/

Comment: Thanks-though I was hoping for this to be done on the server side. My framework is in pythin/django.

Comment: oh sorry. my idea was to open in the server side an UI control like this, render the content, and then save it to an image. But I have no idea about how to do it pythin/django :(

Comment: Think I will use something along the lines of this http://webscraping.com/blog/Webpage-screenshots-with-webkit/